# Power issues with Nodemcu and Sim800L

Tags: power-supply, arduino, esp8266, battery-operated, nodemcu

I am building a project and i am facing weird anomalies while implementing it. Keep in mind in a student a fairly new to this. So the problem is that i have a usb- charging module connected with a battery, it has out + and out - pins. I have connected the battery to a breadboard from where the connections go to sim800l and nodemcu. The voltage requirment of the the nodemcu is 3.3V and the the sim800l needs 4.4-3.4V. The battery im using is a 3.7V lithum ion battery which has a voltage range of 4.2-2.7V. Throughout my testinv i have made sure that the voltage of the battery remains around 4V via a multimeter. When i only connect the sim800l it connects to the network and gprs everytime but when i connect the nodemcu and sim800l simultaneously, the sim doesnt connect to the network and shows low power error (Led blinks 7 times). If i connect the sim800l first and let it connect to network and gprs and then i connect nodemcu later, it then maintain gprs connection. If i connect the nodemcu first and then i connect the sim800l, then the sim module doesnt connect to the network of gprs and shows low power error via blinking lights. I have measured the voltages across the sim modules both when its connected alone and when connected with nodemcu and both readings are close to 4.0V.
What is the problem? I cant seem to figure it out

Comment: Please post Vcc oscillogram when the fault happens.

Comment: I dont have that apparatus with me, ive just noticed from the countless testings that these behaviors occur, the sim on its own seems to work, with nodemcu it only works when the sim is connected to the network first. And it almost never works simultaneously.

Comment: Try adding a very large value capacitor to the battery power input. Say 1000 uF +.

Comment: I dont have a 1000uF capacitor with me. I did however try a 470uF capacitor and the results seem to be the same as without the capacitor. Do you know what the problem here is? there is also an update that if i connect the nodemcu first and then i connect the sim800l, it doesnt connect to the network or gprs and shows low power error lights

Comment: Post back when you have made the measurement.

Comment: Be nice to have a schematic or block diagram